# What is this element of python?

Tags: django, python-2.7

I was reading some code in the django tutorial and i found this

```
<ul>
{% for athlete in athlete_list %}
   <li>{{ athlete.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

what is athlete?, where can I find mor information about how to use this?

I searched for list, but they seem to have restricted functions such as append and index.

Comment: Yikes, your formatting is horrible. I don't even know what to do to try to fix it, since you've splattered HTML all over the place. Please use the [standard markdown code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/#code) to make your code legible -- prepend four spaces to every line of a code block. Remove the hand-written HTML and the needless back ticks, select all the code, then hit the `{}` button in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`athlete_list` is a context variable that has been passed to the template.

`athlete` is an element of `athlete_list`. In this case, it looks like `athlete` is a model object with a `name` property. In which case, `athlete_list` is probably an `athlete` query set, or list of objects.

Have a look at the [Django template tag reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed it is a list of objects.